# Problem Trying to upgrade webform to latest version using composer

Tags: webforms, composer

I've been trying to upgrade webform 5.19 to version 6 using composer but I keep getting this error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Problem 1
drupal/webform_ui 5.19.0 requires drupal/webform 5.19.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/webform[5.19.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

I asked over at the module's help and was to to try here. Has anyone seen this or have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try `composer update drupal/webform --with-dependencies`.

Answer (score 2):

Manually editing composer.json to add `"drupal/webform": "^6.0"` did the trick.